# How to get filter criterion in google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

is it possible to get the filter criterion applied on the spreadsheet using google app script.

i want to write a function that works only on filtered data in the spreadsheet and need to get a way of getting fileterd rows in a range.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can check on similar Stack Overflow topic via [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74619494/google-app-script-getfilter-and-getrange-does-not-return-desired-filtered-resu/74654396#74654396).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.

There's an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=524) opened regarding this, you might want to *star* it to keep track of updates and kind of vote for it.

Comment: where is the issue opened. Where can I star it?

Comment: you must be logged in your Google account, and there's a star icon before the issue title. Also, since you're new here, you should accept an answer (check mark near the answer votes) when you feel you got a good one.