# Google App Script - getFilter and getRange does not return desired filtered results

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a filter applied to a sheet.  I want to return just the data from the filter and not the entire range of the sheet.

```
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEET_ID).getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME)

  const filter = sheet.getFilter();
  // This returns the entire sheet's range rather than the filtered range.
  const range = filter.getRange().getValues();
```

Based on the code above, why aren't I getting the desired behaviour according to [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter#getRange()) from Google?

Comment: filter.getRange() just returns the range that the filter applies to.  And getValues() get's all of the values in that range.  You probably should request a new method like getFiilteredValues();

Comment: Obviously `getFilteredValues()` doesn't exist right now.  You're saying there's no way to currently do this with what Google App Script offers?  Outside of just using JS to filter the data.  I wanted to avoid to improve performance.  I already have a sheet filter, why can't I actually use that in code?

Comment: Also the way the docs describe how this works when getRange() is used with getFilter() is deceiving:

`Gets the range this filter applies to.`

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with returning filtered values and realized it is the most convenient to make a code that will skip FilterCriteriaBuilder class with functions.

For that reason I developed a code on [this link](https://github.com/NikolaPlusEqual/GoogleAppsScriptFilters/blob/main/Functions).

https://github.com/NikolaPlusEqual/GoogleAppsScriptFilters/blob/main/Functions

Simple example for using functions from the repository:

```
function example(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var range = ss1.getRange(1,1,ss1.getLastRow(),5).getValues();
  output = whenNumberGreaterThan(10, range, 3);
  Logger.log(output);
}
```

whenNumberGreaterThan(number, rng, col) is the function from the repository, which will return all values from the rows in the range, that have satisfied "number greater than 10" criteria in the 3rd column of the range. The function is the alternative for FilterCriteriaBuilder Class function whenNumberGreaterThan(number) on [this link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria-builder).

Just copy entire Functions file code into you .gs file and call desired function.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged, this will be worthless if the link expires. Please summarize the minimally required content to make the answer self-sufficient

Comment: @mozway Link-only answer is posted because there was no specification of the filter criteria in the initial question. User asked how to get filtered data instead of entire range and exactly that was the reason why I developed functions that will skip that issue. Only thing I could do is to post an example with one filter criteria, so the user could get how to apply some of the functions from the repository on his own solution. Do you consider that as an improvement, or we should ask the user to further explain which filter criteria was applied on his sheet?

Comment: This is a good idea

Comment: @mozway I edited my answer and I hope this could be helpful for the user. I do not have enough reputation for commenting on initial question, so if user needs to have further explanations for some particular function, I hope he will do it for his own benefit, as well as the benefit of the other Stack Overflow users with similar issues in the future...

Answer (score 0):

You can get just the values the active filter displays by removing the values in the data that are in rows where [isRowHiddenByFilter(rowPosition)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#isrowhiddenbyfilterrowposition) returns `true`.

That said, using JavaScript's `Array.filter()` would offer much better performance than making multiple API calls to find which rows are hidden.